# calculating bounded polygon from intersecting linestrings

Tags: boost, computational-geometry, boost-geometry

I am using boost geometry and I am trying to calculate a "bounded" polygon (see image below) from intersecting polylines (linestrings 2d in Boost geometry). Currently, my approach is i) to get all the intersection points between these lines and then ii) "split" each line at the intersection points. However, this algorithm is a little bit exhaustive. Does anyone know if boost geometry has something more efficient for this?

[image]

Moreover, how could I get the segment (or vector of points) for each linestring that lie withing two intersection points? For example, for the green linestring, if I have the two red intersection points, how can I get the linestring between these two points (vector of points containing the two red intersection points and the two interior blue points)? Is there any "split"-like functionality in boost geometry?

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you intersecting a polyline against a square grid ?

Comment: Hi, many thanks the comment. The intersections can be between polylines and lines. For a given set of polylines or lines I would like to calculate the bounding polygon as depicted in the image above. For the given example we have 3 lines and a polyline.

Comment: Can it be between two polylines ? How many lines/polylines at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, it must handle cases of two polylines, as well. For example, it can be a closed region between two polylines, each representing a hemi-circle. However, the number of polylines can be any providing that they can enclose/form a bounding polygon.

Comment: What do you mean any ? One million ?

Comment: Polylines cannot represent a hemisphere !?

Comment: I don't think you are after a "bounding" polygon. Rather a "bounded" polygon.

Comment: Apologies for the hemisphere. I corrected it. Regarding the number of polylines, I am not expecting to exceed five to seven.

Comment: Five to seven is quite different from "any". This makes a big difference. How many vertices in a polyline ? I must admit that the possible cases are not clear yet to me.

Comment: Are the polylines monotonous in one direction ? Or convex ?

Comment: I can neither predict the number of the polylines nor the points that discretise them, I am afraid. This depends entirely on the user. According to this particular application, I am not expecting more than five polylines. However, I can't see any reason why the user cannot break the polyline to smaller ones. The polylines can be pointing to any direction. The only condition is to form a closed loop or a bounded polygon.

Answer (score 2):

From the given description, it seems that the (poly)lines intersect in pairs to form a single loop, so that the inner polygon is well defined. If this is not true, the solution is not unique.

As the number of lines is small, exhaustive search for the pairwise intersections will not be a big sin. For 5 (poly)lines, there are 10 pairs to be tried, while you expect 5 intersections. Forming the loop from the intersections is not a big deal.

What matters most is if Boost Geometry uses an efficient algorithm to intersect polylines. Unsure if this is documented. For moderate numbers of vertices (say below 100), this is not so important.

If the number of points is truly large, you can resort to an efficient line segment intersection algorithm, which lowers the complexity from O(n²+k) down to O((n+k) log n). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm. You can process all polylines in a single go.

If your polylines have specific properties, they can be exploited to ease the task.

Comment: Hi Yves, many thanks for the valuable input. The polylines indeed intersect in pairs. As you correctly pointed out the first part of my question has to do with whether boost geometry has a more efficient algorithm to return all intersections of a given set of polylines (e.g. sweep, etc.). The second part of my question regards that given the calculated intersections, how I can get the (rest of the) polyline points that form the edges of the bounded polygon? For example, in my first post and; for the green line, how I could get the blue points between the intersection points?

Comment: @GioR: you need to know to which segments an intersection belongs (i.e. have the endpoints indexes along the polyline), one way or another. Then cutting the useful section and merging the pieces to generate a single outline is a simple matter.